# GPU passtrhough, subsystem lost

Tags: nvidia, qemu, libvirt, pci-passthrough, gpu-passthrough

When I do lspci on my **manjaro linux host** I can see that my Nvidia GPU is a part of `[1025:1409]` subsystem (as is everything else on my machine). The GPU is in its own IOMMU group and has vfio-pci driver.

When I pass through my GPU into **windows 11 guest** in qemu the device instance path in windows device manager is `PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1D52&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_A1\4&12829B10&0&0014`.

So subsystem is lost. Because of that I have problems with the drivers.

First the driver installer couldn't find compatible hardware. Then I replaced all occurences of 1025:1409 sybsystem related to my device (1D52) to 0000:0000 subsystem in `nvacig.inf` (found no occurences in other *.inf files). Now driver installation starts but fails after some time.

How do I fix it? It feels like if the subsystem was right then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix it myself by disabling "driver signature enforcement".
I actually disabled it earlier as per instructions that I was following. But it gets enabled again after reboot and I was not expecting that.